# Navbar Bootstrap Mobile Menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Apparently with my bootstrap navbar, no button appears on the mobile version, testing on my Windows Phone.
I am using the following code for my navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" style="height: 75px"></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#">Name</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Placeholder1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Placeholder2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Placeholder3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Inside this code, how would I add the button for the mobile version of my website?

Comment: Look here at the basic example of a Bootstrap template . This includes the burger icon. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the navbar code I always use on my websites.

```
 <!-- Navigation bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
        <li><a data-scroll href="#top">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- End navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- End container -->
</nav><!-- End Navigation bar -->
```

Comment: yeah it seems CasperEngl was missing the button element

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll report back if I find any errors.

Comment: I have uploaded the new navbar to my web server, you can see it here http://arculo.com

Comment: Do you have links to jquery and bootstrap js files ?

Comment: http://arculo.com/js/navbar.js
http://arculo.com/css/bootstrap.css
http://arculo.com/css/style.css

Thought I would add all three of them.

Comment: I just use the standard bootstrap.js file along with Jquery 1.11.2.

Comment: That is what I do too, I am overriding with my style.css. I use the 2.1.3 version of jQuery though.

Comment: Maybe the order in which you load the bootstrap.js file is not right. In my site it is in the head tags but it is the last js file that I load.